# Android EditText loses Focus on TabChange

Tags: android, tabs, focus

In my application, I have multiple tabs.
In one of the tabs, I have an EditText which needs to have focus by default when the user moves to that tab.

But, when the tab is changed, the EditText loses focus.

I tried all this.

In my Xml file to the EditText to which I want to have the focus.

```
<requestFocus />
```

In my java code onCreate()

```
userIdInput.post(new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run() 
       {
        userIdInput .requestFocus();
       }
    });
```

And also,

```
userIdInput.setFocusable(true);
    userIdInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    userIdInput.requestFocus();
```

But still, the focus is lost when the tab is changed. Can anyone tell me what I might be missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a different container layout for each of your tabs, implement the `setOnFocusChangeListener()` for that container layout (one which contains the edit text) and inside the `onFocusChange()` check if the container layout has focus, if yes, use

```
userIdInput.post(new Runnable() 
{
  public void run() 
   {
    userIdInput .requestFocus();
   }
});
```

Comment: I have defined the content of each Tab under different Activities and use spec.setContent(new Intent(this, xxx.class));